# Can SCTP bundle chunks from different streams

Tags: sctp

Can SCTP bundle chunks from different streams in a single packet or do the chunks have to be from the same stream?

Comment: Unfortunately, the common NAT variant (NAPT) used for IPv4, does not support SCTP, only TCP, UDP, and ICMP, which is a big reason to use IPv6.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. SCTP packets are made of multiple chunks which can be DATA type and each DATA chunk encodes its own stream identifier (see RFC 4960 section 3.3)